# Check if an item is greater than another by at least 1

Tags: python, tuples

I want to validate if `item_position` can move diagonally towards `item_target` so I want to make sure both the x, and y value of `item_position` is greater than at least 1 but less than two of item target

Below is the code I have tried:

```
def can_jump(item_position, item_target):
     if item_position[0] >= 1 and item_position[0] <= 2 and item_position[1] >= 1 and item_position[1] <=2:
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can write the code? Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "greater than at least 1 but less than two", correct me if I am wrong but is that not the same as "Greater than one and smallen than the other".

Comment: I want to validate if item_position can move diagonally towards item_target so I want to make sure both the x, and y value of item_position is less than 1 of the item_target

Comment: It seems description of question is wrong.

Comment: How would you change the description to better reflect on the problem?

Comment: Not sure what you want ?!  I guess you want to check item_target[0]-item_positon[0] == 1 and item_target[1]-item_positon[1] == 1  ?!

Comment: by at least 1 but less than 2 ??  the difference is (2, 1) for (3, 4) vs (5, 5), is it True ?

Comment: Yes since item_position has to move diagonally towards item_target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def can_jump(t1, t2):
    return (1 <= t2[0]-t1[0] < 2) and (1 <= t2[1]-t1[1] < 2)
```

Output

```
can_jump((3, 4), (4, 5))                                                                         
True

can_jump((3, 4), (4, 4))                                                                         
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
def can_jump(item_position, item_target):
   return abs(item_position[1] - item_target[1]) > 1

print(can_jump((3,5), (4, 5))) # prints False
```

Try to make you code as simple as possible, Usually the one which is simplest is best
**Edits**
I didn't see your less than 2 line:

```
def can_jump(item_position, item_target):
       return 2 > abs(item_position[1] - item_target[1]) > 1

print(can_jump((3,5), (5, 9))) # prints False
```

Comment: Thanks, just a question, is the abs function neccessary?

Comment: I agree the code needs to be simple, but for understanding things better could you extend your code

Comment: Here, no, but we should look whether the absolute difference is greater than 1.. in case if second value is greater than first, it would result negative value. So, you should use `abs()` for that case.. if you think that case would not arive @code_legend, that is OK

Comment: `abs(item_position[1] - item_target[1]) > 1` means if the absolute difference of the 2nd indices (1st position) is greater than 1, it should result `True`. Did it help you though?

Comment: I see, so can_jump((3,5), (5,6)) would return True? I need to validate if item_position can move diagonally towards item_target so I want to make sure both the x, and y value of item_position is less than 1 of the item_target

Comment: No, because abs(5 -6) equals 1 which is not greater than 1, because you asked for greater than 1. If you want `True` for greater than or equal to 1 you should use `>=` in the return ststement

Comment: See the edited post please, and accept my answer by clicking on tick button, if you found this answer helpful

Comment: It seem second code always return False for tuple of two integers.

Comment: Yes @JasonYang because integers differ by atleast 1. It will result `True` if you provide floats having difference between 1 and 2

Comment: But it failed if the difference is 1.

Comment: Yeah, that what code_legend asked for: `greater than' not 'greater than or equal to'. You can add an `=` though, if you want